# PrimeNG styling issues in Angular 2

Tags: css, angular, npm, primeng, primeng-calendar

I'm trying to use PrimeNG's Calendar component, but the styles aren't working. These are all the steps I took:

I installed PrimeNG using the command: `npm i primeng`

I imported the CalendarModule in my app.module.ts:

`import {CalendarModule} from 'primeng/calendar';`

and put it in my imports[]:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgbModule,
    SocketIoModule.forRoot(config),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    CalendarModule,
  ],
```

I added the stylesheets to my angular.json:

```
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/bootstrap/theme.css" ,
          "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.css",
        ],
```

And I inserted a p-calendar into one of my components like so:

```
<label for="publishedAt">Published At:</label>
<p-calendar
    [(ngModel)]="news.publishedAt"
    name="publishedAt"
    id="publishedAt"
    required
    #publishedAt="ngModel"
    showTime="true"
    hourFormat="12"
>
</p-calendar>
```

But my calendar looks like this:

[image: broken calendar]

Is there something I missed?

Comment: The code you provided has /themes/bootstrap/theme.css, but on setup page of primeng is no css named like this, the only css with bootstrap in its path are

`primeng/resources/themes/bootstrap4-light-blue/theme.css`
`primeng/resources/themes/bootstrap4-light-purple/theme.css`
`primeng/resources/themes/bootstrap4-dark-blue/theme.css`
`primeng/resources/themes/bootstrap4-dark-purple/theme.css`

check if you are implementing the existing stylesheet from nodemodules primeng css in angular.json

Comment: @godocmat I tried that but unfortunately it didn't make a difference.